# Update the column based on the recurrence of phone num

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which I have the following data below:

```
phone_num repeat_next date
12345          -1   2017-01-01(initially repeat_next values will be -1 default )
12345          -1   2017-01-02(if the same phone number exists in other day then by output should be as below)

phone_num repeat_next  date
12345          1      2017-01-01 (which is max date of phone repeat number minus latest date )
12345         -1     2017-01-02
```

In this case, my repeat_next value should be updates as above (it is (2017-01-02) - (2017-01-01))

So I need to update based on the next occurrence date

For example, if the same phone number comes again like:

```
phone_num  repeat_next    date
12345           1      2017-01-01
12345          -1      2017-01-02
12345          -1      2017-01-08
```

then in that case the output should be as below

```
phone_num repeat_next date
12345          1      2017-01-01
12345          6      2017-01-02
12345         -1     2017-01-08
```

In this case it is (2017-01-08) - (2017-01-02)
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is unclear. Since there is no order in a table, all lines with the same date (for example 2017-01-01) are unordered. Also, I have no idea what you want to achieve, or what you are asking ;)

Comment: I have edited the question..the dates are different. its like if any phone number is repeating then i need to update the repeat_next column based on latest date(2017-01-08) minus previous max date (2017-01-02).  date is in YYYY-MM-dd format